# Constructing a query in a class method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am looking to perform a query on a model of mine (postgresql) as a validation.

I want to count the number of times a paticular skill_id occurs in the model, and if it is `>=` 3 for example then validation fails

so far I have

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
 mount_uploader :media, MediaUploader
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :skill

 validate :num_of_images

 def num_of_images
   skill_id = self.skill_id
   number = self.count(skill_id: skill_id)
 end
end
```

but i get

```
(undefined method `count' for 1:Fixnum):
```

What method/query do i need to use to count the records

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update question with model rb files and an example of when it fails the validation, I dont understand what you are trying to do yet

**Update**

Replace self with Document

```
Document.where(skill_id: skill_id).count
```

In that context self is not the clase but a Document object

Comment: he hasn't got a rating of 50 to place a comment.. so @ManuGambino please refrain from using the answer button as a comment loader

Comment: I know :(. I dont have the rep yet